# laravel how to check if session variable is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-session

How can I check if this session is empty, here example

```
 @elseif {{Session::get('package_id')}}=null
 @include('index.customer.customerpackage')
```

and how to check if {{Session::get('package_id')}}=1 then Free else Paid

Comment: It's better to prepare a variable in a controller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
@elseif (session()->has('package_id'))
```

to verify if it's in session or in case it might be in session but also set to null, you can use:

```
@elseif (session()->get('package_id'))
```

Comment: Why not just use `@elseif (session('package_id'))`?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$value = $request->session()->get('package_id', function () {
    return 'Return this if session key does not exist';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now Laravel 8.XX there are several ways:

To determine if an item is present in the session, you may use the has method. The has method returns true if the item is present and is not null.

```
if (session()->has('users')) {
    //
}
```

To determine if an item is present in the session, even if its value is null, you may use the exists method.

```
if (session()->exists('users')) {
    //
}
```

To determine if an item is not present in the session, you may use the missing method.

```
if (session()->missing('users')) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Check By Using It

```
if(session()->has('my_variable')) {
    // my_variable exists
} else {
    // my_variable does not exist
}
```

You Can Also Use This Way

```
if(empty(session('my_variable'))) {
    // my_variable is empty
} else {
    // my_variable is not empty
}
```